# JList actionlistener "delay" in selecting item

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have a `JList` populated by what is initially an `ArrayList<SomeClass>` which I convert to an array.  This `JList` is then wrapped in a `JScrollPane` and displayed on a `JFrame`.  When I select an item in it, the first item selected is correct, but after that it seems to select the previous item.  So if I have an `ArrayList<String>` populated "Number 0", "Number 1", "Number 2", etc. and I select 19, 18, 17 in that order, the output is as if I'd selected 19, 19, 18:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DemoFrame extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener{
    ArrayList<String> strings;
    public DemoFrame(){
        strings = new ArrayList();
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
            strings.add("Number " + i);
        }
        JList demoList = new JList();
        demoList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        demoList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(demoList);
        listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 500)); 
        demoList.setListData(strings.toArray());
        this.add(listScroller);
        demoList.addListSelectionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(listScroller);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
        if (!lse.getValueIsAdjusting()){
            System.out.println(lse.getLastIndex());
            System.out.println(strings.get(lse.getLastIndex()));
        }
    }
}

public class SODemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoFrame demo = new DemoFrame();
    }
}
```

Output from selecting 19, 18. 17:

> run: 19 Number 19 19 Number 19 18 Number 18

However, Output from selecting 0, 1, 2:

> run: 0 Number 0 1 Number 1 2 Number 2

Why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods of interest in the ListSelectionEvent class:

> public int getFirstIndex()
>
> Returns the index of the first row whose selection may have changed.
>
> public int getLastIndex()
>
> Returns the index of the last row whose selection may have changed.

So a selection event actually involves 2 list elements, the one gaining focus and the one losing focus

Comment: I'm not 100% certain I understand you here.  Am I reading you right that you're saying that the listener is returning "19" because that selection has changed (i.e. it has been deselected)?  If that's the case, how do I overcome it?

Comment: @MrB If you call getLastIndex() it will return the element having the highest index in the list model involved in the given ListSelectionEvent. If you go from a higher index to a lower one, that one will always be the element you deselect. What you should do instead is print the currently selected item (has nothing to do with the selection event itself) by invoking getSelectedValue() on your JList instance..

Comment: You're a star.  Thank you